# libp2p-rust: How to implement fire-and-forget pattern

Tags: rust, libp2p

Some sub-protocols in my application require sending to concrete peers just a single message. Does [libp2p-rust](https://crates.io/crates/libp2p) allow to send a message to some `PeerId` without negotiating a substream?

If there is a way to do this with libp2p-rust I would be happy to hear how.